# JavaScript: How to figure out, if a div is on the middle of the screen?

Tags: javascript

Is there an easy way to figure out if a certain div is on the middle of the screen? I tried http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/viewport but it needs extra code as well. By middle I mean centered vertically and horizontally.

Isnt there an easier way to figure this out?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by 'on the middle of the screen'? Do you mean anywhere in the viewport, or scrolled to the middle of the viewport?

Comment: What do you mean by 'middle'? Close enough to the middle? Borderline touching the middle? Near the middle? Below the middle? Above the middle? A 1px wide/tall div precisely in the middle? Offset [n] of the middle? To the left of the middle? To the right of the middle? Malcolm in the middle? The center of the div in the middle? Bottom left corner touching the middle? Top right corner touching the middle?

Comment: By middle I mean centered vertically and horizontally.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery solution:

```
var offsetLeft = $('#whatever').offset().left;
var offsetRight = ($(window).width() - (offsetLeft + $('#whatever').outerWidth()));
var isInMiddle = offsetLeft == offsetRight;
```

Edit: If you want not only want to check if it's centered vertically, do the same also for the offsetTop and bottom

Comment: How would that look like? I tried using top and outHeight etc, but its not working. Can you help?

Comment: basically you can change left to top, width height and right to bottom